# combine files for makefile lead to make No targets

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have the following file and directory structure which contains a lot of files and directories:

```
$ tree
input/
├── C-1-28558666
│   ├── MGRF-C1_S10_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz
│   ├── MGRF-C1_S10_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz
│   ├── MGRF-C1_S10_L002_R1_001.fastq.gz
│   ├── MGRF-C1_S10_L002_R2_001.fastq.gz
│   ├── MGRF-C1_S10_L003_R1_001.fastq.gz
│   ├── MGRF-C1_S10_L003_R2_001.fastq.gz
│   ├── MGRF-C1_S10_L004_R1_001.fastq.gz
│   └── MGRF-C1_S10_L004_R2_001.fastq.gz
├── C-2-28577664
│   ├── MGRF-C2_S11_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz
│   ├── MGRF-C2_S11_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz
│   ├── MGRF-C2_S11_L002_R1_001.fastq.gz
│   ├── MGRF-C2_S11_L002_R2_001.fastq.gz
│   ├── MGRF-C2_S11_L003_R1_001.fastq.gz
│   ├── MGRF-C2_S11_L003_R2_001.fastq.gz
│   ├── MGRF-C2_S11_L004_R1_001.fastq.gz
│   └── MGRF-C2_S11_L004_R2_001.fastq.gz 
...
```

Each file name contain R1 or R2. The files with R1 and R2 belongs together and the below commanand uses the two files and a dm6.fasta.bwt file.

```
bwa mem ref/dm6.fasta.bwt input/C-1-28558666/MGRF-C1_S10_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz input/C-1-28558666/MGRF-C1_S10_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz | samtools view -Sb - > BAMs/C-1-28558666/MGRF-C1_S10_L001.bam
```

I have tried to write the following Makefile rule:

```
BAMs/%.bam: $(addsuffix .bwt,${REFERENCE}) $(foreach SIDE,R1 R2, ../MGRF_NGS_KUMARAN-25071046/*/*${SIDE}*.fq.gz )
    bwa mem ${REFERENCE} $(filter %.fq.gz,$^) | samtools view -Sb - > @>
```

However, I have got:

```
$ make -n 
make: *** No targets.  Stop.
```

How is it possible to fix the above Makefile?

Comment: If that's your entire makefile then your problem is that you haven't told make to actually build any files. You've just given it a pattern to match target filenames against. That being said that makefile target/etc. isn't at all going to do what you want.

Comment: I just started with the first rule. How do I tell for the above example to build the files?

Comment: You need to actually tell make to build targets: `make BAMs/file.bam` for example or have a target like `all: BAMs/file.bam BAMs/otherfile.bam ...` in your makefile so make has a default. But like I said your target rule there has a *host* of other problems.

Comment: You use `${REFERENCE}` unmodified in the rule (instead of the `.bwt` suffixed version). *Every* `BAMs/%.bam` file will depend on **every** globbed `R1` and `R2` file (not just ones that match the output file name). You have a trailing `>` on the `samtools` command. And your directory listing says `.fastq.gz` but your makefile uses `.fq.gz` (I don't know which is correct).

Comment: Thank  you, Renaud below has rewritten my Makefile, but it can't handle `R1` and `R2` at the moment.

Comment: You need to take each pair of `*_R1_*.fastq.gz`/`*_R2_*.fastq.gz` files and use them in a `bwa mem ...` call? Is the `.bwt` file the same for all fastq pairs or is there a different `.bwt` file for each pair?

Comment: Yes, each pair of  `*_R1_*.fastq.gz/*_R2_*.fastq.gz` files have to be used with `bwa mem ... `. The `.bwt` file stays always the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first problem comes from the fact that pattern rules do not create targets if they are not explicitly requested. So, you need to explicitly list the targets to make. In the following example they are listed in the `BAMS` make variable and then used as dependencies of the `all` target, which is the first of the makefile. `all` is thus the default goal and typing `make` or `make all` will build all `bams`.

Your second problem is to handle the pair of `R1` and `R2` dependencies of each `bam` target. The GNU make static pattern rules are really useful in such situations:

```
REFERENCE := ref/dm6.fasta
DIRS := $(wildcard input/*)
R1S  := $(foreach dir,$(DIRS),$(wildcard $(dir)/*_R1_001.fastq.gz))
RR1S := $(patsubst input/%_R1_001.fastq.gz,%,$(R1S))
BAMS := $(patsubst %,BAMs/%.bam,$(RR1S))

all: $(BAMS)

$(BAMS): BAMs/%.bam: $(REFERENCE).bwt input/%_R1_001.fastq.gz input/%_R2_001.fastq.gz
    @mkdir -p $(dir $@); \
    bwa mem $^ | samtools view -Sb - > $@
```

`target: target-pattern: prerequisite-pattern` is a static pattern rule.

GNU make also has several functions (`call`, `eval`, `foreach`) that can be used in more complex examples:

```
REFERENCE := ref/dm6.fasta
DIRS := $(wildcard input/*)
R1S  := $(foreach dir,$(DIRS),$(wildcard $(dir)/*_R1_001.fastq.gz))
RR1S := $(patsubst input/%_R1_001.fastq.gz,%,$(R1S))
BAMS := $(patsubst %,BAMs/%.bam,$(RR1S))

all: $(BAMS)

define BAM_rule
BAMs/$(1).bam: $(REFERENCE).bwt input/$(1)_R1_001.fastq.gz input/$(1)_R2_001.fastq.gz
    @mkdir -p $$(dir $$@); \
    bwa mem $$^ | samtools view -Sb - > $$@
endef

$(foreach r,$(RR1S),$(eval $(call BAM_rule,$(r))))
```

**Explanations:**

The `RR1S` variable lists all `C-1-28558666/MGRF-C1_S10_L001` stems. It is then used to build the `BAMS` variable that lists the targets. The `BAM_rule` variable is a skeleton of the rule that builds a `bam` target from its corresponding `R1` and `R2` dependencies. `$(1)` is the parameter that will be expanded when using the `call` function: `$(call BAM_rule,foo)` expands `BAM_rule` and substitutes all `$(1)` occurrences by `foo`. Note that some `$` signs must be doubled to be preserved by this first expansion. Finally,

```
$(foreach r,$(RR1S),$(eval $(call BAM_rule,$(r))))
```

iterates over all stems and uses the `eval` function to instantiate one `BAM_rule` per stem, expanded and specialized by `call`.

The normal make expansion will then transform each instance of `BAM_rule` into the rule you would write manually for the given target:

```
BAMs/C-1-28558666/MGRF-C1_S10_L001.bam: ref/dm6.fasta.bwt input/C-1-28558666/MGRF-C1_S10_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz input/C-1-28558666/MGRF-C1_S10_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz
    @mkdir -p BAMs/C-1-28558666; \
    bwa mem ref/dm6.fasta.bwt input/C-1-28558666/MGRF-C1_S10_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz input/C-1-28558666/MGRF-C1_S10_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz | samtools view -Sb - > BAMs/C-1-28558666/MGRF-C1_S10_L001.bam
```

Comment: Thank you, but I can not figure out how 2 FASTQ (**R1** and **R2**) files produce 1 BAM file e.g.  `input/C-1-28558666/MGRF-C1_S10_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz input/C-1-28558666/MGRF-C1_S10_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz | samtools view -Sb - > BAMs/C-1-28558666/MGRF-C1_S10_L001.bam`?

Comment: Is the `_001.fastq.gz` constant or do you have also `_002.fastq.gz`... ?

Comment: Yes, `_001.fastq.gz` is constant and there is no `_002.fastq.gz`.

Comment: I updated my answer to show you how to use static pattern rules or `foreach-eval-call` to handle your R1 and R2 dependencies.